# Is this a WinForm Control? 

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just wondering if this control can be used in my WinForm application. Please refer to the image below:

[image]

Comment: Please don't just throw "C#" at the end of titles. The tags are good enough for that. Besides, this question has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Thanks John for the comment. This is noted.

Comment: @yonan2236, what am I wrong, I've referred to an article which described almost same thing what you're looking for, but I've to a down vote! Would you please explain me why, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello @JohnSaunders, can you please answer be the above question, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain: you mean can I answer the question that yonan asked? It's been answered by 6 others.

Comment: Hello @JohnSaunders, I asked to "@yonan2236, what am I wrong, I've referred to an article which described almost same thing what you're looking for, but I've to a down vote! Would you please explain me why, thanks for your time.". Please see my above comment. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain: how would I know the answer to that question? I didn't downvote.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, actually the asker looking for a control as that is not present in .NET framework, however I've given a reference of such control and have got a down vote though my reference is appropriate! My query is: what the reason of getting down vote for my answer? If answer is correct then is it possible to put a down vote? How can I know that who vote me for a specific answer? Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain: since I didn't give you the downvote, and since I have no idea who gave it to you, and since that person didn't post the reason for the vote, I am left with no answer to your question. Maybe the voter was just having a bad day.

Answer (score 2):

That *particular* control is not in .NET. There are, however, third party controls that provide the same (or at least very similar) appearance. One example is the [DevExpress NavBar](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/NavBar/).

(And no, I am in no way affiliated with DevExpress; I've just used their products for years and have been happy with them)

Comment: Hello @AdamRobinson, may I know why I've got down vote, I've referred to a control according to the asker, but I've got down vote :(, may I know why? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Md.EliasHossain I couldn't tell you; I'm not the one that downvoted your answer.

Comment: Also, just on an unrelated note, it's not necessary to end every comment with "Thanks for your time" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This control was not written in managed code, so it not consumable by .NET directly.

Comment: I don't recognise it as a public part of the native API either.

Comment: is there any third pary dll or alike?

Comment: @yonan2236 - I don't know. You will need to search.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's rich component in C#.It's LeftTab